# Svelte how to have duplicate keys in a keyed each

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit

I have a simple clicker app, that stores the number as a list (500 being [5,0,0]). Here's my current implementation:

```
{#each numbers as number (number)}
    <h1 class="score-text">{number}</h1>
{/each}
```

It can count up to 10, but 11 won't work as they are the same number.

```
each.js:135  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot have duplicate keys in a keyed each: Keys at index 0 and 1 with value '1' are duplicates
    at validate_each_keys (each.js:135:10)
    at Object.update [as p] (ScoreCounter.svelte:13:23)
    at update (scheduler.js:119:30)
    at flush (scheduler.js:79:5)
```

What could I do to fix this?

Just placing a bunch of  elements with `numbers[0]` through `numbers[15]` works, but I feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the loop index as key:

```html
{#each numbers as number, index (index)}
  <h1 class="score-text">{number}</h1>
{/each}
```

Comment: @Nex: Note that this is not a proper key; it's equivalent to not setting it. For primitives like numbers this is fine, though, since they don't an identity that can be tracked.